# elastix cdr stop working

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, elastix

CDR was working before 19 march. Unfortunately i dont remember what kind of changes i made to configuration, but this exactly not changes to CDR config.

elastix 2.4.0 asterisk 11.7.0 mysql 5.0.95

```
elastix*CLI> cdr show status

Call Detail Record (CDR) settings
----------------------------------
  Logging:                    Disabled
  Mode:                       Simple

/etc/asterisk/cdr.conf
[general]
enable=yes
unanswered = yes


/etc/asterisk/cdr_mysql.conf
[global]
hostname = localhost
dbname=asteriskcdrdb
password = *MYPASSWROD*
user = asteriskcdruser
userfield=1
;port=3306
;sock=/tmp/mysql.sock
loguniqueid=yes


mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'asteriskcdruser'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for asteriskcdruser@localhost                                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'asteriskcdruser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'HASHHERE' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `asteriskcdrdb`.* TO 'asteriskcdruser'@'localhost'                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What do you mean "stop working"?

Comment: it means CDR worked before, but now does not work

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Asterisk console at load to see if there are errors in mysql channel driver? Look at the mysql server logs as well so see if there are connection or authentication issues.

Answer (score -1):

Fix it by deleting:

```
/var/log/asterisk/cdr-csv/Master.csv
```

and reload modules